# Can I boot Windows 10 from VHD and then spin up the same OS in virtual box?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vhd

Could I run the same Windows installation bare-bones and then virtually (inside another OS).

Use cases:

1. Boot Windows 10 natively to have full access to resources.
2. Boot Linux natively, spin up the same Windows installation in virtual box, do a Windows only task and then close the VM, all without having to reboot Linux.

So, can I go back and forth between the two without having issues Windows licence or device drivers?

Comment: Which Windows version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't legally.

The
[Microsoft License Terms](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm)
paragraph d (iv) says:

> **Use in a virtualized environment**. This license allows you to install only one instance of the software for use on one device, whether that device is physical or virtual. If you want to use the software on more than one virtual device, you must obtain a separate license for each instance.

You have here one physical device and one virtual device, which together makes two.

The only way you could make it legal would be to create the virtual machine with
the physical Windows partition as its **Raw Disk**.
That way, you have only installed one Windows version on only one disk.

This works because section 2 says:

> a. **License**. The software is licensed, not sold. Under this
> agreement, we grant you the right to install and run one instance of
> the software on your device (the licensed device), for use by one
> person at a time, so long as you comply with all the terms of this
> agreement. Updating or upgrading from non-genuine software with
> software from Microsoft or authorized sources does not make your
> original version or the updated/upgraded version genuine, and in that
> situation, you do not have a license to use the software.
>
> b. **Device.** In this agreement, “device” means a hardware system
> (whether physical or virtual) with an internal storage device capable
> of running the software. A hardware partition or blade is considered
> to be a device.

Since "device" equals "disk", this would be legal.